# Why do I get a "No property 'count' found for type..." runtime when running Spring Boot 3 native app written in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, graalvm

When creating a minimal Kotlin Spring Boot 3 application, I am get a runtime error when executing the native (GraalVM) image. The error message is:

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository.count(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); No property 'count' found for type 'Customer'
```

where 'Customer' is a data class entity.

I created a simple gradle based application with SpringBoot v3-RC1 consisting of one class

```
package org.test.nativedemo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository

@SpringBootApplication
class NativeDemoApplication
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<NativeDemoApplication>(*args)
}

interface CustomerRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Customer, Int>

data class Customer(@Id val id: Int?, val name: String)
```

when running (through Gradle) with the following `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
   id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.0-RC1"
   id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
   id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.16"
   kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.20"
   kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.20"
   kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.7.20"
}

group = "org.test"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
}

dependencies {
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
   implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1")
   implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
   implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
   implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
   runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
   runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
   kotlinOptions {
      freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
      jvmTarget = "17"
   }
}
```

It compiles and builds native image. There is a runtime error stating

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository.count(kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); No property 'count' found for type 'Customer'
```

Comment: Does it run when it is not a native image?

Comment: Yes, it does compile/run correctly when targeting the JVM.

Comment: Then I guess the NativeHints are missing something in Spring or, more likely, the kotlin package including CoroutineCrudRepository. Maybe run with the tracing agent: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image.advanced.using-the-tracing-agent

Comment: I will give that a try. 
The code presented above was without some (non-related hints) for brevity.
After doing some more digging, I have found the same code works correctly in 3.0.0-M5.

Comment: Additionally, I have confirmed that changing the spring release version to 3.0.0-RC1 on https://github.com/jamesward/nks/tree/main/bootiful (from https://youtu.be/2MYSLP2vgps) also results in the same error.

Comment: You should definitively file a bug with them then

Comment: Also facing this issue. I have a JVM application using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa Version 2.6.4. Something weird going on with the count() method. If I switch CoroutineCrudRepository to plain CrudRepository, the problem disappears.

Comment: Full source code can be found at https://github.com/ketronkowski/spring-kotlin-native

Comment: feels like you misconfigured something check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2728#issuecomment-1299976026

Comment: Once GraalVM v22.3.r17 came out, and I changed to target it with SpringBoot v3.0.0. The error no longer happens.